# How to get the classID for item using GetAssetClassInfo in the Steam Web API?

Tags: steam-web-api

The Steam WebAPI allows for downloading game and player items.  The [GetSchema](http://wiki.tf2.com/wiki/WebAPI/GetSchema) service, however, does not included the item attributes and description.  This information is contained in the [GetAssetClassInfo](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/w/index.php?title=WebAPI/GetAssetClassInfo) service.  The required parameters for this service include a `classid`, but the documentation is not at all clear where this identifier is defined or derived.  **How do I get the classID for a given item?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hopped onto the IRC channel of the maintainers of the [TF2 Wiki](http://wiki.tf2.com/wiki/Main_Page) to ferret out this piece of information and then updated the service documentation.

Essentially, you have to do a 'GetSchema' call to get all the items, then call the [`GetAssetPrices`](http://wiki.tf2.com/wiki/WebAPI/GetAssetPrices) service.  While the service describes getting the pricing information of items, it also reveals a mapping between the `defindex` from the `GetSchema` service and the `classID`.  With that mapping in hand, you can then call the `GetAssetClassInfo` service using the `classID`.

This information is now officially documented in the wiki. :)

Comment: This only works for craftable, tradeable items.  Uncraft and untradable items have different class ID's that reflect this status.